# Extend angular-material buttons with loading animations

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I'm trying to create a generic solution in Angular 12 for disabling (and displaying a spinner) when a button is clicked, until the API responses.

In order to achieve this, I intend to use a similiar approach to [angular-material button](https://github.com/angular/components/blob/master/src/material/button/button.ts).
Basically, I would like to use an attribute selector for a custom button-component and apply it to the button element.

The simplified code below works as expected, but when adding the 'app-button-loading' **alongside** the mat-raised-button the application fails, throwing an *NG0300 error: Error: NG0300: Multiple components match node with tagname button*.

```
  <button app-button-loading color="primary"> Click me! </button>
```

Please note that if app-button-loading would be a Directive it would work just fine.

I tried to also specify the material selectors, but this doesn't seems to help:

```
selector: "button[mat-button][app-button-loading], button[mat-raised-button][app-button-loading]"
```

I managed to achieve a satisfying enough solution using a Directive instead of a Component with an attribute selector (programmatically creating a mat-spinner component)  and it works just fine, but i would like to add some stylings and I prefer to not have them in the global styles.scss.

**TL;DR;**
Is it possible to add a Component with an attribute selector to a button **alongside** with the material selector *mat-raised-button* (or any other)? Or Angular simply does not allow the usage of Components in this way?

```
<button mat-raised-button app-button-loading color="primary"> Click me! </button>
```

Also, I have created a simplified [demo stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-sdxuh2?file=src/app/app.component.html) if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm trying to create a solution in Angular 12 for disabling (and displaying a spinner) when a button is clicked, until the API responses.

If this is what you're trying to do, just use the mat-spinner component (google Mat Spinner). Your button will look like this.

```
<button mat-button [disabled]="apiLoading">
 <mat-spinner *ngIf="apiLoading"></mat-spinner>
 <span *ngIf="!apiLoading">Click Me</span>
</button>
```

Where apiLoading is a boolean in your TS file, to be toggled when your API begins.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I'm trying to have a generic reusable solution. Having to add a spinner everywhere is not a desirable solution. Already found one that works ok and it's clean enough,with a directive + mat-spinner, but, as I said, it has some limitations. I could come up with a custom wrapper against button, but then I would have to expose all properties of that. Hence the component with an attribute selector idea.